# mysql how to fill in missing calendar months from a table and pad the missing values with the previous value within a group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that for every item a different budget can be set for each country for the month. The table only stores the budgets at the time they are changed - so if there is a missing month, this means the budget has stayed the same. I am trying to pad missing values with the budget of the previous month (within the same country_code group) so I can see every month's item-country_code budget.

I have finalised my query to get myself 2 tables that look like the below (apologies if the table set up below doesn't quite work - I get these tables through many queries and subqueries of other tables). Note: table b is just a calendar table that i have build with all the years and months. table g is the table I am trying to transform and pad values to get the final output table. maybe table b is not even required...

---

```
CREATE TABLE b
(date_ym INT PRIMARY KEY NULL
);

CREATE TABLE g
(item_number INT NULL,
country_code CHAR(2) NULL,
budget INT NULL,
budget_set_date INT NULL,
earliest_budget_set_date INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO b VALUES
(201706),
(201607),
(201608),
(201609);

INSERT INTO g VALUES
(1, 'AU', 100, 201606, 201606),
(1, 'AU',NULL, 201609, 201606),
(1, 'US' NULL, 201606, 201606),
(1, 'US', 200, 201607, 201606),
(1, 'US', 100, 201608, 201606),
(1, 'DE', 50 , 201609, 201609),
(2, 'AU' NULL, 201608, 201608),
(2, 'DE', 200, 201606, 201606),
(2, 'DE', NULL, 201608, 201606);
```

The final output of the join should then look like this:

```
 item_number  | country_code | budget | date_ym  
 1            | AU           | 100    | 201606  
 1            | AU           | 100    | 201607  
 1            | AU           | 100    | 201608  
 1            | AU           | NULL   | 201609
 1            | US           | NULL   | 201606
 1            | US           | 200    | 201607 
 1            | US           | 100    | 201608 
 1            | US           | 100    | 201609 
 1            | DE           | 50     | 201609
 2            | AU           | NULL   | 201608  
 2            | AU           | NULL   | 201609
 2            | DE           | 200    | 201606  
 2            | DE           | 200    | 201607  
 2            | DE           | NULL   | 201608 
 2            | DE           | NULL   | 201609
```

I've attempted a bunch of things but can't get the correct answer - cross joining the calendar table to my table for all values where the b.date_ym >= g.earliest_budget_set_date but that isn't working. And also using a variable to capture the last budget set to bring forward to the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would use `cross join` to generate the rows and then a subquery bring in the values.

I am a little unclear what the exact logic is for the date comparisons, but the idea is something like this:

```
select ic.item-number, ic.country_code, b.date_ym,
       (select g.budget
        from g
        where g.item_number = ic.item_number and
              g.country_code = ic.country_code and
              g.budget_set_date >= b.date_ym
        order by b.date_ym
        limit 1
       ) as budget
from (select distinct item_number, country_code from g) ic cross join
     b ;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you - this helped me get the correct answer. I wasn't able to get the budget this way since the order by date_ym didn't get the latest date_ym (I had duplicates). So I added a rank to each budget:  set [at]rank := 0; and ([at]rank := [at]rank + 1) as ranking and then pulled in the budget as you suggested.